# Scale nabla to height of fraction

Tags: beamer, math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I have an equation where the nabla symbol should be the same height as the fraction. Instead, it's about half the height. How do I fix this?

[image: Wrong sized nabla symbol]

Comment: Are you sure that the nabla symbol should actually extend in size?

Comment: nabla is a letter not a stretchy symbol, as the images in the answers below show it will look really quite odd if you scale it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure this looks the best, but you did ask to scale `\nabla` to the fraction height.  `scalerel` does this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\scalerel{\nabla}{\frac{\norm{F(q) - D}^2}{2\norm{D}^2\sigma^2}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is really quite painful to behold:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes it is, but as they say in the world of retail business, "the customer is always right!"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Given the upvotes, I can only conclude there is a grotesque fascination with it, sort of like how traffic slows down to rubberneck at accident scenes.

Comment: I'm sure you will be relieved to know that my honour is intact and I didn't vote for you:-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It does look odd. Unfortunately I have my own "customer" for this ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is no surprise that `\nabla` does not get bigger beside the fraction: this symbol is not supposed to scale, usually. However, it can be enlarged manually using larger font sizes. To do that easily, you could use the command `\mathlarger` from the `relsize` package. They can be nested to get bigger font sizes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\mathllarger}[1]{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mathlllarger}[1]{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\mathllllarger}[1]{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
1 step:
\[
\mathlarger{\nabla}\frac{\norm{F(q) - D}^2}{2\norm{D}^2\sigma^2}
\]
2 steps:
\[
\mathllarger{\nabla}\frac{\norm{F(q) - D}^2}{2\norm{D}^2\sigma^2}
\]
3 steps:
\[
\mathlllarger{\nabla}\frac{\norm{F(q) - D}^2}{2\norm{D}^2\sigma^2}
\]
4 steps:
\[
\mathllllarger{\nabla}\frac{\norm{F(q) - D}^2}{2\norm{D}^2\sigma^2}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the scaling yourself you can use `\scalebox`, combined with `\raisebox` to position the symbol vertically.

But as noted in the other answers this is not really a good idea, the symbol should have a 'normal' height of one line and not be twice as big as the other symbols.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
% change the 2 in \scalebox{2} to influence the amount of scaling
% change the -4pt in \raisebox{-4pt} to influence the vertical position
$\raisebox{-4pt}{\scalebox{2}{$\nabla$}}\frac{\lVert F(q)-D\rVert^2}{2\lVert D\rVert^2\sigma^2}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]